# Class of Named Ranges - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am in the process of continuously updating and improving a financial model built in Excel with VBA macros enabled that is in active use by multiple people.  Primarily, these templates are used as budgets for different projects, so there are many created all the time while older budgets are re-visited.

I am the "keeper" of the template while the other users simply use the document.  Whenever I need to push out an update to everyone, it creates an issue because they already have created the budget in an older version of the template and to re-create the budget in the new template would take an inordinate amount of time.

I have gotten around this problem on smaller-scale templates by naming ranges and then applying those named ranges to an old version and then using the named ranges to copy into the same named range in the new version of the template.  However, this was done with individual lines of code to copy each named range.

Is there a way to aggregate a group of named ranges into a class so that Excel can just loop through all of the items in the class and copy the data rather than me needing to code out each line to perform a copy?

Here is a sample of the code that I am currently running:

```
Workbooks(WB_Active_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Names").Value = Workbooks(WB_Secondary_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Names").Value
    Workbooks(WB_Active_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Positions").Value = Workbooks(WB_Secondary_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Positions").Value
    Workbooks(WB_Active_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Numbers").Value = Workbooks(WB_Secondary_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Numbers").Value
    Workbooks(WB_Active_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Bonus_Sharing").Value = Workbooks(WB_Secondary_Name).Sheets("Office Staff Input").Range("Office_Employee_Bonus_Sharing").Value
```

There are dozen of more lines of code similar to this for each named range.  Inside the template, the ranges refer to lists of names of staff, ID numbers, hours worked, etc. and they also span multiple sheets within the workbook with each range of different size.

I am wondering if there is some sort of class that I could place in front of each named range when I define it so that they are treated as a class together and can be looped through.  For example:

```
Office_Employee_Names
```

becomes

```
GroupClass.Office_Employee_Names
```

Then the code could loop through everything in `GroupClass`

Comment: Demonstrate how you are currently doing it. Show some code and we will help you improve it. ALso a visual example of what you're talking about woudn't hurt as it's quite difficult to visualize someones template..

Comment: Do you just mean you want to maintain a list of all the ranges as something you could loop through? If so, you could do exactly that... Create a procedure that defines a string array with all the named ranges. Then, you could always just add new elements to that array as needed and refer to that array in your code... Am I not understanding your problem??

Comment: See my edits to the original post above with sample code.

Comment: I'm kinda disappointed. The days where vba programmers at least tried to look for the most stable solutions seem to be officially over. Guess vba is really becoming what they say: a language to serve quick fixes, no serious application development

Comment: @KimGysen, I appreciate your response below and I am sure that it is an effective solution, but given my current level of knowledge in VBA, the other solution seemed more practical for my purposes.  I seek to make my programs more robust, but probably more so with Excel than other programs, implementation efficiency must be considered.

Comment: I wasn't really referring to you primarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new worksheet in your template that list all these named ranges; read the list from VBA and loop through them.

Comment: An elegant solution indeed.  Do I need to reference the sheet name where the named ranges live?  For some reason, it seemed to be giving me issues although I would assume that Excel can find the named range wherever it lives in the workbook.

Answer (score 3):

IF an MVC pattern would exist in VBA, then a named range *could* represent a View object.
I personally have some experience with an MV* pattern where Views also implement events (which are normally delegated to Controller objects).

The benefit of using this approach, is that you will start programming in a much more modular fashion.

I provide an example below:

The structure of an MV* implementation of a simple named range "persons" could have the following class structure:

- cls_view_persons
- cls_model_person

Imagine that `cls_view_persons` represents a view object, then this would mean that you have to instantiate it from a base sub, which will simply be:

```
dim view_persons as cls_view_persons 
set cls_view_persons = new cls_view_persons
```

**1. persons view (example)**

The cls_view_persons class will have a property that defines the range of the class. 
For example:

```
private pRange as new Range
```

You can define the private pRange property in the class constructor.

One of the things that makes Excel buggy, is the fact that you don't know in advance the size of the range, and the fact that mistakes happen, such as a range that was not properly cleared the last time.
This is why it is important to also define the following properties:

- _oRange as Excel.Range
- _sNamed_range as string;
- _lNr_rows as long;
- _iNr_cols as integer;
- _iOffset_x as long;
- _lOffset_y as integer;
- oCollection as Collection (you can also use a dictionary for this)

Note: oCollection is an object that will consist of the different cls_view_persons instances;

and methods:

- Init: class constructor: defining a default range object, or you could pass a range on creation time if you wish to do so;
- get_named_range: returning a range object;
- set_named_range: setting the range object property and creating the named range in the sheet object;
- collection_to_array: converts the collection object into an array;
- clear_range: clearing the range;
- A `render` method that uses the previous three methods and writes data from the created array to the range in a single statement:

  `set pRange = vPersons`

Where vPersons is an array, containing the different persons (see later).

- (A "read" method that reads from the range would be useful as well).

  **2 person model (example)**

A model represents the data logic of your application and is on itself, not necessarily related to one specific view. In this case it is, but a model (or Collection of models) is in principle independent).
A person model could be a class that defines the following properties:

- firstname
- lastname
- address
- country

Either these models are fetched from a database, from an Excel sheet (the latter being the worst scenario, which unfortunately happens the most) or any other source.

Whatever you do, you need to see that you end up with a Collection object that you can feed to the View object.
Once this is done, the View object should manage its own. All interpreting and rendering is delegated to this object from that moment on.
This means:

- Verify the dimensions;
- Clear the previous results;
- Render the range on the screen (ie. setting the new dimensions, creating the named range in the sheet, converting the collection into an array, and writing the array to the screen).

You will see that this approach has many benefits in terms of:

- Maintenance;
- Less bugs;
- Modular (and transferrable) / encapsulated properties / methods;
- Dynamically adaptable;
- You can read from any data source, if you only write an intermediary "translator" module.

Comment: I realize that this seems complex, but believe me when I tell you that it isn't. Once you get used to working with an MVC or MV* workflow, you will quickly get used to the conventions and find that it is a lot more pleasant to work with. For the simple reason that you will be able to debug much faster (encapsulated objects), write extensions much faster, find and solve bugs a lot easier (instead of spaghetti coding your modules, not knowing the consequence of a change) and perhaps most importantly, develop code that is re-usable while you know that it will make your objects and methods stable.

Comment: you should add this as a canonical answer to a question, because here it might not get get many views, but on a well-written question that you pose yourself, it could be more useful...+1

Answer (score 0):

I often retrieve data from Names by:

Workbook.Names contains all Name Objects, and each Name Object its properties

```
Dim WBook As Workbook
Dim WName As Name

Set WBook = ActiveWorkbook
For Each WName In WBook.Names
    Debug.Print WName.Name, WName.RefersToLocal
Next WName
```